# Set view values (Bindings) whith index of array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

**Clarification: I am asking about how to access (iterate over) View Bindings stored in an array NOT how to access an array element by index**

I have bindings for my views and I want to set text-values to them depending on the index of an array.

Here is my example code of the array and a binding (this obviously works, because I have a resource in strings.xml).

`binding.bnd1.text = "HelloWorld"`

Is there a way to access bindings by index of the array like the following code, so that the command knows I don't want to give it some string but the resource of the strings.xml? (I know this code does not work, its for visualization)

```kotlin
    val bindings= arrayOf(R.id.bnd1, R.id.bnd2, R.id.bnd3)

    binding.bindings[0].text = "HelloWorld"
    binding.bindings[1].text = "HelloAgain"
    binding.bindings[2].text = "SomeText"
```

Comment: is your question answered? It would be great if you give feedback if people take effort and try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your needs right but maybe this solves your problem:

```
val bindings = arrayOf(binding.bnd1, binding.bnd2...)

bindings[0].text = "Hello World"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change a value by its index

```
val bindings = arrayOf("bnd1", "bnd2", "bnd3")
bindings[0] = "foo"
bindings.forEach{ binding -> println("$binding")}
// result: foo bnd2 bnd3
```